# FirebaseAuth: getGoogleApiForMethod() returned Gms: com.google.firebase.auth.api.internal.zzal@489

Tags: firebase, flutter, firebase-authentication

When I am trying to phone authntication I am getting below error.

```
W/BiChannelGoogleApi(12340): [FirebaseAuth: ] getGoogleApiForMethod() returned Gms: com.google.firebase.auth.api.internal.zzal@489
```

I have checked the same error in Stackverflow and other places but not getting proper solution anywhere.

**chnages in pubspec.yml**

```
dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter

  # The following adds the Cupertino Icons font to your application.
  # Use with the CupertinoIcons class for iOS style icons.
  cupertino_icons: ^0.1.2
  firebase_core: ^0.3.0+2  //new
  firebase_auth: ^0.8.1+1  //new
```

Note -- added //New to highlite the lines which i have added in above file.

Added below line at the end of **app/build.gradle**

```
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

android/build.gradle

```
buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = '1.2.71'
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.2.1'
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.2.0'
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
}

rootProject.buildDir = '../build'
subprojects {
    project.buildDir = "${rootProject.buildDir}/${project.name}"
}
subprojects {
    project.evaluationDependsOn(':app')
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

android/app/build.gradle

```
.....
android {
    compileSdkVersion 28
    .....
    defaultConfig {
        ....
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 27
        ......
    }
    .....
    dependencies {
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:16.1.0'
//    implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.0.0'
}

apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

android/app/gradle.properties

```
org.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx1536M
android.useAndroidX=true
android.enableJetifier=true
```

I am using AndroidX.

Comment: Have you enabled Phone as a Sign-In method in the Firebase console like Adding your App fingerprints (as mentinoed in https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/firebase_auth)? I missed it couple of times, so just checking.

Comment: you are talking about adding project and app.. correct? all those verifications are done.

Comment: have you replace latest google service.json file?

Comment: Yes I have done it. I even don’t know what this error mean?if you know please explain me so that I can debug it further.

Comment: i think its dependency  related problem , can you share project level gradle?

Comment: Thanks, @Mayur  for looking into it. I have edited the question with build.gradle of both app and project level.

Comment: Downgrading the Firebase Version, implementation  'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:11.0.4'  or  implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:11.4.2'

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. But I am using AndroidX as well. Provided details of mine `gradle.properties` file. I feel if i will downgrade firebase:firebase-auth to 11.0.4 i will get error. Sorry, I am just guessing. I will try your suggestion by EOD today.

Comment: the next line might be `I/flutter ( 7385): Instance of 'AuthException'` ...which would need to be handled, eg. `Log.e(LOG_TAG, e.getMessage(), e);` ...see https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=is%3Aissue+com.google.firebase.auth

Comment: Not getting exactly!

Comment: @Mayur -- i tried to use  'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:11.0.4' but no luck.

Comment: have you checked this github issue https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/19804 ?

Comment: check whether your play services are updated in your testing device

Comment: I had the same issue, resolved by enabling "Allow more than one account for single email address" in Firebase Console

Answer (score 15):

I recently solved this issue.
Basically there are many reason for this this error because this error returns when FirebaseAuth entry point failed to execute.
One of the reason of getting this error which I faced is My **Emulator was't connected to Internet**
So turn **the internet on** inside emulator also.

Comment: The same to me!

Answer (score 6):

I lost a few hours on this one, so let me share my experience on this.

Gms stands for ["Google Mobile Services](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Google_mobile_services)", and its basically an addon API to Android developed by Google that allows to connect to a bunch of Google-provided services.
If you use flutter, this is probably wrapped by flutter packages you use such as firebase_auth, flutter_facebook_login or/and google_sign_in.

This error may sometimes be handled by the higher level components, so if you have that error, it doesn't mean your configuration is wrong or it won't work.
In my case I had this error with successful end result when I was logging using Google Sign in, something like this:

```
info flutter.tools W/BiChannelGoogleApi( 4106): [FirebaseAuth: ] getGoogleApiForMethod() returned Gms: com.google.firebase.auth.api.internal.zzak@8116b2c
info flutter.tools D/FirebaseAuth( 4506): Notifying id token listeners about user ( lCZZZZJELWhGUZZZZB3vDklZZZZ2 ).
info flutter.tools D/FirebaseAuth( 4506): Notifying auth state listeners about user ( lCZZZZJELWhGUZZZZB3vDklZZZZ2 ).
info flutter.tools I/flutter ( 4506): FirebaseUser({uid: lCZZZZJELWhGUZZZZB3vDklZZZZ2, photoUrl: https://lh5.googleusercontent.com/-ZZzir_P-ENw/AAAAAAAAAAI/AAAAAAAAAAA/PpxhiXg_ISk/s96-c/photo.jpg, isAnonymous: false, etc....
```

I have a dart call `print(fireUser);` in my code so we see it's a success.

But in the case of Facebook Auth, I just had this, and nothing happened after that, but on the Facebook server side, login *was succeeding* as I could see events in Facebook dev console.

```
info flutter.tools W/BiChannelGoogleApi( 4106): [FirebaseAuth: ] getGoogleApiForMethod() returned Gms: com.google.firebase.auth.api.internal.zzak@8116b2c
```

And nothing else after in the log, so something was stuck in the process.

My problem was I mixed two applications App Id and Secret. I'm a bonehead sometimes, but the thing is there's *zero warning or specific error* nowhere, so here are a list of things that can fail with Firebase and other plugins:

- Make sure you have properly configured the sign-in provider (google, facebook, etc.) in Firebase console
- Upgrade all flutter packages. I personnaly don't use package versions, I use all flutter packages latest version. And I use AndroidX.

In the specific case of Facebook Auth (I find Google Sign In much easier to integrate):

- make sure your looking at the good app
- make sure the App ID and App secret are the good one. In Facebook dev console, check the Basic Settings there.
- make sure you have added the "Facebook Login" product. If you don't see it in the left menu, in Facebook dev console, check the Dashboard and add it.
- in the "Facebook Login" product settings, make sure you have added the "Valid OAuth Redirect URIs" that Firebase console gives you (in the Facebook Sign-in provider config). You can check it in the "Redirect URI validator" tool lower in that page.
- in the Basic Settings of the app, if you use flutter (=> mobile platforms), make sure you have an IOS section/platform and and Android section/platform. To achive that you can do it manually "Add platform", or use the Quick Starts.
- in the end, the IOS section can contain only the "Bundle ID"
- and the Android section should containe the "Google Play Package Name", the "Class Name" and at least one "Key Hashes" (for debug). If you don't know how to create the hash, use the "Facebook Login" quick start.

Hope this helps

Answer (score 5):

I had this error but it happened because I was trying to create an account with same email on my app, I had to remove the account from database and authentication.

My returned code is a little different from yours.

```
[FirebaseAuth: ] getGoogleApiForMethod() returned Gms: com.google.firebase.auth.api.internal.zzal@**5bfaa19**
```

Comment: This was exactly what happened to me.

Comment: how much time we need to wait after removing data?

Comment: It's instant normally.

Answer (score 3):

This might be due to an incompatible version of google play services on your testing device.

If it is an emulator, try switching to another image and check if you are on the lastest version of play services.

Note that only Android N (API 24) and above supports update of play services via playstore.

Answer (score 2):

For me I got this stacktrace

> getGoogleApiForMethod() returned Gms:
>   com.google.firebase.auth.api.internal.zzak@a73de51

I forgot to enable the `Sign-In Provider` in the Firebase Console. I solved it after enabling `Phone Provider` under the sign-in method tab of Authentication Section.

Also I got another kind of same error

> getGoogleApiForMethod() returned Gms:
>   com.google.firebase.auth.api.internal.zzak@a73de51 I/flutter ( 2870):
>   The format of the phone number provided is incorrect.

Initially I sent only mobile number without country code. Then I just sent the phone number with country code.

For example : `+91 8811111111`

It worked perfectly.

Comment: Worked for me after wasting 1 day on this particular issue..Vinoth  Happy coding

Answer (score 2):

I had this error and i couldn't connect with email/password after updating my libraries in my pubspec.yaml file.

To resolve this error, I also updated my gradle file (build.grade) :

```
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.6.1'
    classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
    classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.3'
}
```

and my gradle-wrapper.properties file, I updated the following line :

```
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-6.3-all.zip
```

Comment: Thanks this resolved my problem when using `com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.3`

Answer (score 1):

This is a dependency issue, you may want to review your firebase setup again. I ran through a flutter app, and had the same exact issue.

Answer (score 1):

In my case, I was just being lazy and using a 3 character long password. I don't know If this may help someone else one day.‍♂️

Answer (score 1):

Its because "oncomplete listener " which automatically verified that phone number are correct.  Its internal API but we want sms verification. 
So it will not send sms on that number on which app is installed.  Send to another device number,  it will work definitely

Comment: you are right. sms is not sent on that number on which app is installed. but after switch off and on, one time, getting the sms. but with different number provided, everytime getting sms on other device.

Answer (score 1):

I have solved this problem.
i have  a cleared solution of it

follow the steps:

1. first go to firebase , then authentication and enable the call verification.

2.second thing is: phone number is in the format of  +countrycode then phonenumber(like +918282.....).

hope this is helpful

Answer (score 1):

If you are going with the phone authentication, please check whether you are providing the country code or not. That worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

```
W/BiChannelGoogleApi(12340): [FirebaseAuth: ] getGoogleApiForMethod() returned Gms: com.google.firebase.auth.api.internal.zzal@489
```

These types of error codes are pretty much useless. Try

```
Log.i("flag", "signInAnonymously:failure", task.exception)
```

inside the auth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword or similar method.

When authenticating google will look for a password with at least more than 6 characters.

You can see some examples here: https://github.com/firebase/quickstart-android/tree/master/auth

Answer (score 0):

I got same error while I was trying to make Email/Password authentication and lost few hours, Finally realized that I didn't Enable Email/Password authentication in firebase account.

Answer (score 0):

Weird behaviour,
Using android Emulator, connected with firebase
when using phone keyboard its working fine but using my PC keyboard, facing this issue

Answer (score 0):

Something must have gone wrong on my emulator. I simply ran the app on a new emulator and it worked just fine. It also ran fine on my device.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it's late for your solution, but in my case was just no WiFi connection in testing device (Emulator)

Answer (score 0):

I tried everything, this error cost me around three hours, just to make sure if you are trying to send OTP from emulator it will not work since it requires a network, just something else you can check.
Good luck!!