# Flutter firebase registration process not completed

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, visual-studio-code, cross-platform

I followed steps in Angela course to register new user using firebase and this message displayed.
When i click on register button no thing happens and user not added in firebase.

the message:

```
I/BiChannelGoogleApi( 2003): [FirebaseAuth: ] getGoogleApiForMethod() returned Gms: com.google.firebase.auth.api.internal.zzaq@278608d
W/DynamiteModule( 2003): Local module descriptor class for com.google.firebase.auth not found.
W/GooglePlayServicesUtil( 2003): Google Play Store is missing.
```

and this is the dependencies i use :

```
dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter
  cupertino_icons: ^0.1.2
  animated_text_kit: ^2.2.0
  firebase_core: ^0.4.0
  firebase_auth: ^0.14.0+5
  cloud_firestore: ^0.12.0
  google_sign_in: ^4.0.1
```

note: i use genymotion emulator

Comment: try using the command "Flutter clean" in the terminal , and RESTART your emulator. Most of the errors in flutter are solved by this. If the error still persists try checking this answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54733720/firebaseauth-getgoogleapiformethod-returned-gms-com-google-firebase-auth-api